# php tidy_parse_string

Tags: php

`$result = tidy_parse_string($str);
echo (is_object($result) ? $result->value : $result);`

$str - html с кириллицей, а на выходе получаются крякозябры. Не получается поменять кодировку. Что бы выводился корректный html с норм кодировкой.

То html сущности выдает, то кривая кодировка.

Пробовал разными методами поставить кодировку, не получается, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Укажите 1)Крякозябры  2) кодировка в $str  3)кодировка исходника php. 4)кодировка html страницы (браузера)

Comment: Попробуй установить кодировку `tidy_parse_string($str, $config, 'UTF8')` которая используется в документе php. Конфиг из документации `$config = array('indent' => TRUE, 'output-xhtml' => TRUE,  'wrap' => 200);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8');
```

Попробуйте в начале файла послать заголовок